# Angular 9+, How to get data from route?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to get data property from route

game-router.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { GamesBoardComponent } from './containers/games-board/games-board.component';
import { ENavigationTypes } from 'src/app/navigation/models/ENavigationTypes';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: { navigationType: ENavigationTypes.lobby },
    component: GamesBoardComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class GamesRoutingModule {}
```

In my component's `ngOnInit` I have:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('data');
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

When I change route nothing happens, my question is what am I doing wrong and if I do, how can I get data from route in component?

Comment: are you trying to get the data in the `GamesBoardComponent` or a parent component? the route structure is a tree of routes, each with their own params and data, and the corresponding route node gets injected to each component, they don't all get the leaf.

Comment: @bryan60  I am trying to get the data in the app component

Comment: the data isn't on the root route that's injected to the app component, it's on the leaf route injected to the `GamesBoardComponent`, this is why you're not seeing it in the app component ... what you're trying to accomplish here and why is relevant, as this seems like suspect app design.

Comment: @bryan60 thanks bro it works in GamesBoardComponent